# How to add frame in razor view? Two webpages in single window

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on ASP.NET MVC4 project.
How can I add frame in razor-view? Actually, I want to add two frames in which one frame is having menu (all the links) and in second frame I have related WebPage(Controller/View).
Menu frame is fix and another frame will be changed according to menu selected using Ajax call.

Comment: from what I understand iframes are a big security risk so if you are just wanting 2 views on one page look into partial views.  you mentioned ajax so search loading partial views with ajax

Comment: hello Matt, Can you give me some small example of partial view

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=load+a+partial+view+with+ajax+in+mvc&oq=load+a+partial+vie&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3887j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8  lots of examples here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is good to use Partial View rather .
Here I am putting basic example of Partial View that I have used in my project.

Main View:

```
 </fieldset>
     <div>
     <div style="width:30%; float:left; height:470px">

     <table border="2" cellspacing="35">
     <tr>
     <td>
      @Ajax.ActionLink("Member notificaiton", "MemberNotification", "Admin", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result" })
     </td>
     </tr>

     </table>

        </div>

        <div id="result" style="width:70%; float:right; height:470px" >
       </div>
         </div>
     }
      </fieldset>
```

MemberNotification Controller:

```
public ActionResult MemberNotification()
    {
        return PartialView("MemberNotification", new MemberNotification());
    }
```

And finally, generate your partial view for this MemberNotifcation Method.